# Add signal to 230 volt distribution line and filter it

Tags: induction

How to add a distortion signal to the 230 volt distribution line that failure induction motors to work unless we filter it at the meters to prevent electricity theft.

And if that is difficult, what can I do to prevent electricity theft?

Comment: Use DC instead of ac

Comment: Is bold print the new capitals?

Answer (score 2):

Any "distortion" large enough to upset a motor is going to involve substantial ammounts of energy to produce and is going to be a massive pain to filter out.

I highly doubt that such a system could be made economical. I would expect that the costs would massively outweigh the savings from reduced electricty theft.

Comment: Not to mention the waste of electricity in generating and then filtering out that distortion, is obviously going to be higher than any theft that cannot be found with conventional means.

Comment: @Asmyldof a similar technique is used for signaling. Eg. for high and low tarif or for switching street lights. These signals are too small to upset a motor, but you can clearly see them on an oscilloscope. A fair amount of power is used to insert the pilot tone into grid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zellweger_off-peak#/media/File:Zellweger_Ripple_Plant_motor_generator_injection_set.JPG (observe it daily at I believe 07:00 and 19:00 in Eindhoven).

Comment: @jippie I know. But by definition a distortion powerful enough to upset a motor needs a lot of force behind it, since the incoming 230V is a low impedance path, or else it can't drive the motor. And also, those tones are actually useful.